# Using Math.round() in a method vs. directly

Tags: java, floating-point, double, long-integer

I have this code here:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Math.round(12.5));
        System.out.println(round(12.5));
    }

    public static double round(double integer) {
        return Math.round(integer);
    }
}
```

When I run the code it outputs:

```
13
13.0
```

Why is it that when I run `Math.round()` normally inside the main method, it provides an integer value, while it provides a double value inside the "round" method? I know that my method is of type "double" but Java doesn't let me change it to "int." Any reason behind this? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the call to :

```
Math.round(12.5)
```

12.5 is evaluated as a `double` and the method, [**`Math#round`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(double)), with the following signature is called:

```
public static long round(double a)
```

because it returns a `long` it will print without any decimal place (*i.e.,* 13). In the second print statement, however, you use:

```
public static double round(double integer) {
    return Math.round(integer);
}
```

which returns a `double`, hence the decimal value 13.0.

Answer (score 4):

[The first method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-double-) returns a `long`, the second method returns a `double`. When you print the second, you get the decimal place. Some equivalent example code:

```
public class Test {

    public static final void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(roundL(12.5)); //prints 13
        System.out.println(roundD(12.5)); //prints 13.0
    }

    //equivalently, float->int is another option
    public static long roundL(double input) {
        return Math.round(input);
    }

    public static double roundD(double input) {
        return Math.round(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: The first method actually returns a long. public static long round(double a)

Comment: There are overloads for both `float->int` and `double->long`. Either would be acceptable and works here, though I suppose it's more canocially correct since `12.5` is a `double` literal. Fixed.

Comment: The beginning of this answer is kinda confusing.  The method you link to as the "first" method is actually the second method the OP uses in their code, and neither one of the methods in the `Math` class returns a `double`.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong `Math#round` is the first function OP uses? The second method being `Main#round`

Comment: @Rogue `Math#round(float)` is the first method OP uses, but you link to `Math#round(double)`, which is the method OP calls from within `Main#round()`.  `Math#round(float)` and `Math#round(double)` are two different methods, with different return types.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong `12.5` is a `double`, he used `Math#round(double)` in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

In your `round()` method, you specify that the return type is a `double`, which is a floating-point type.  So your call to `Math.round()` returns an integer type (`long`), but the compiler can't return that, because you specified that your method has to return a `double`.  So the compiler, being smart, casts your integer to a floating-point value before returning it so it can still comply with the method header.  When you print out a floating-point value in Java, it always adds a `.0` to the end just to be clear that it is a floating-point value.  See my comments below:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // This returns an integer, so it prints out as 13:
        System.out.println(Math.round(12.5));

        // This returns a floating-point value, so it prints out as 13.0:
        System.out.println(round(12.5));
    }

    // Here's your culprit:  public static --->double<---
    // Since the return type is double, this method must return a double
    public static double round(double value) {
        // This is an integer:
        long i = Math.round(value);

        // This gets automatically casted to a floating point:
        return i;
    }
}
```

You can also see the differences in a much simpler example, like so:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // This is an integer type:
        int i = 13;

        // This will print out 13:
        System.out.println(i);

        // This is a floating-point type:
        double d = 13d;

        // This will print out 13.0:
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```